# Appending 'Tokens' to HTTP request (Samsung TV)

Tags: javascript, http, samsung-smart-tv

I'm writing a streaming Application on Samsung Smart TV

I need the Player to append an 'Access Token' to the media segment URL
  For eg., if the URL in the manifest file is http://satn.com/01/1.ts, I need the player to append the Token to the URL., like : http://satn.com/01/1.ts&token=XXYYZZ

1. Is there a way this can be accomplished ?
2. Is playerPlugin.SetPlayerProperty (3, customdata, customdata.length) a possible option for this requirement ? (I think 'customdata' in 'SetPlayerProperty' is used only during Playready DRM "License Acquisition requests")

Thanks
S R

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that the easiest way is generating manifest file dynamically from server.
2. playerPlugin.SetPlayerProperty can not be used for your purpose.